# What is the difference between "drop" and "dump"? When should I use each?

Tags: meaning, verbs

I do not know the difference meaning using these two verbs when you 'throw' something in the floor. For example, in the sentence: "I **dumped/dropped** my wallet on the street."

It may be a very silly question, but I did not find anything about it.

Comment: I dropped my toast butter-side down on the floor, so then I had to dump it in the garbage.   See https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=drop+meaning and  https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=dump+meaning

Answer (score 4):

In this particular context, WordNet defines both the words as follows:

> drop(v): the act of dropping something; "they expected the drop would
>            be successful"
>
> dump(v): throw away as refuse; "No dumping in these woods!"

As you can see, *dump* is a much more negative word as it refers to getting rid of an object (example: *to dump the waste*). *Drop* on the other hand, is a neutral word and could be applied to anything (example: *they dropped the price to induce more sales*).

Answer (score 4):

**Dumped** usually refers to something that is discarded intentionally to get rid of something that is not desired. **Dropped** is more general and can be used for an accidental abandonment such as the wallet in your case.

> (As defined on dictionary.com)
>
> [**Dump**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/dump) - to throw away or discard garbage, refuse, etc. (*usually in a negative connotation*)
>
> [**Drop**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/drop%20?s=t) - to let or cause to fall. (*much broader meaning*)